# Load images to application bar in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I'm developing Windows phone apps and I'm new to it,I'm using below code to add PNG image to application bar at runtime

```
this.ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
this.ApplicationBar.Opacity = 1;
this.ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;

ApplicationBarIconButton btn = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
btn .IconUri = new Uri("/Resources/car.png", UriKind.Relative);
btn .Text = "Car";
this.ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(btn);
```

[image]

But image is not loading it shows 'X' inside application bar circle, i tried also in design using below code

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Resources/car.png" Text="Car" IsEnabled="False" />            
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="About" />
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

but did not work, My image size is 48 x 48 pixels, white foreground graphic for the button in 26 x 26. Did i miss something,Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the properties of the image file in the project: you should have `Build Action` set to `Content` in order to the file go with the final .XAP file